# How to combine rows / add their values according to information in other (data.)table?

Tags: r, data.table, lookup

I have information stored in two data frames / data.tables and I would like to use the information stored in the second one (my lookup table) to add / collapse rows in my first one.

My first data.table looks something like this:

```
ID    Sample01    Sample02    Sample03
1        1            2           3
2        0            1           2
3        2            0           1 
4        5            2           1
```

My second data.table (distance matrix) looks something like this:

```
0    12    4    1
12    0    3    5
4     3    0    6
1     5    6    0
```

I would like to add the values of rows in my first data.table, if the attribute in the second, which displays distances, is smaller than 2.

It should then look like this (rows 1 and 4 are added, as the distance is <2):

```
ID    Sample01    Sample02    Sample03
1        6            4           4
2        0            1           2
3        2            0           1
```

As the data is extremely large, I would prefer to work with data.table, but I can also work with other packages, any help is appreciated!

Edit:

This would be a real-world example of table 1 (dput):

```
structure(list(v_j_cdr3 = c("TCRBV02-01-TCRBJ01-01-SLGGmhcLFF", 
"TCRBV02-01-TCRBJ01-01-SLGhLmhcLFF", "TCRBV02-01-TCRBJ01-01-SLLLGchcLFF", 
"TCRBV02-01-TCRBJ01-01-SLLmGmhcLFF"), HIP08805 = c(6.4439e-05, 
0, 0, 8.69177e-05), HIP17837 = c(6.01681e-05, 0, 0, 0), Keck0006_MC1 = c(2.48385e-05, 
4.96771e-05, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7ffb190066e0>)
```

This would be a real-world example of table 2 (dput):

```
structure(list(`1` = c(0, 2, 3, 2), `2` = c(2, 0, 4, 3), `3` = c(3, 
4, 0, 2), `4` = c(2, 3, 2, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7ffb190066e0>)
```

Edit2 : solution (without deletion of rows as the comments made me realize that I should not do that).

```
diag(matrix) <- 99
pos <- which(matrix<2,arr.ind = T,useNames = F)
datasubset_raw <- datasubset
for(j in 1:nrow(pos)){datasubset[pos[j,1],] <- datasubset[pos[j,1],]+datasubset_raw[pos[j,2],]}
```

Comment: would be great if you shared the example data with dput().

Comment: So the sum of values is only based on the first columns of your second table ? Or it needs at least a couple of distance <2 ?

Comment: @Ronak Shah It seems that the second table is a distance matrix.

Comment: @sindri_baldur that's correct! I edited accordingly.

Comment: @PaulEndymion I would like to add rows that are similar / small distance. If two rows have a distance of 1, they are added. Of course, if one of them has also distance 1 with other rows, these are added as well. I want to "enhace the degree of sharing between samples", by reducing 0 values by adding similar rows together.

Comment: @RonakShah the rows 1 and 4 have distance 1 and will thereby be added up.

Comment: What happens if an i is close < 2 distance to more than one other i?

Comment: @sindri_baldur then that row would be added to more than one other row, which would hopefully be  what is happening biologically.

Comment: @Nicholas But then if, say row A is of distance 1 to row B and row B of distance 1 to row C, but A of distance 3 to row C ? do you still add all of them up ?

Comment: @RomainB. I would add the raw value of A to B, B to A, and of B to C, C to B, but not A to C. You would have to make sure not to add the "cumulated" values to others, only the raw values. In the end you would have cumulated values that indicate how present similar sequences are in the data. You will have redundancies (A to B and B to A), but this should be ok (I hope).

Comment: Maybe one solution could be that the table with raw data is duplicated in memory and then row by row the raw data is checked to see to which row this data should be added (by referring the distance table). After the rows are done, the second duplicated table should have all added up values. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you should do a loop for all situations on your dataset, but this idea might help you

```
df1 <- data.frame("ID"=c(1,2,3,4),"Sample01"=c(1,0,2,5),
              "Sample02"=c(2,1,0,2),"Sample03"=c(3,2,0,1))
# df1
#   ID Sample01 Sample02 Sample03
# 1  1        1        2        3
# 2  2        0        1        2
# 3  3        2        0        0
# 4  4        5        2        1
dist_matrix <- matrix(c(0,12,4,1,
                       12,0,3,5,
                       4,3,0,6,
                       1,5,6,0),nrow = 4,ncol = 4)
#> dist_matrix
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0   12    4    1
#[2,]   12    0    3    5
#[3,]    4    3    0    6
#[4,]    1    5    6    0
```

Lets assume you are not interested in diagonals for the condition, so it should be > 2

```
diag(dist_matrix) <- 999
```

Position with distances < 2 (1 and 4)

```
pos <- which(dist_matrix<=2,arr.ind = T,useNames = F)
# pos
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    4    1
# [2,]    1    4
for(i in 1:nrow(pos)){pos[i,] <- sort(pos[i,])} # sort
# pos
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    4
#[2,]    1    4
pos <- unique(pos) # your final vector
#pos
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    4
```

Sum then up

```
df1[pos[1],2:4] <- df1[pos[1],2:4]+df1[pos[2],2:4]
#df1
#  ID Sample01 Sample02 Sample03
#1  1        6        4        4
#2  2        0        1        2
#3  3        2        0        0
#4  4        5        2        1
```

Delete 4th position

```
df1 <- df1[-pos[2],]
# df1
#   ID Sample01 Sample02 Sample03
# 1  1        6        4        4
# 2  2        0        1        2
# 3  3        2        0        0
```

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot, I modified a little bit to suit my needs a bit better and put the answer in the original question!